# Declare a variable Registry in VBA?

Tags: c++, c, vba, excel

New to VBA here. We can decare a variable as "Register" in C/C++ for very-very frequently accessed variable, ex- Loop iterator variables.

Does similar system exist in Visual Basic for Application. I am programming in EXCEL VBA and pulling data from some other applications.

The nature of my algorithm need 6 levels of nested loops, so would like to make them faster. They have already been running since last 30 min :D

Comment: Current C/C++ compilers just disregard the `register` keyword (they do a better job than that anyway). And AFAIU VBA is _interpreted_, so this doesn't make much sense anyway.

Comment: I would look at what work the loop is doing, rather than the loop itself. VBA is compiled to bytecode(and this can happen at runtime), so optimizations are to be gained from reducing the work done in the body of the loop, rather than how fast it can add 1 to a variable

Comment: I would use a different architecture. VBA is not really designed for heavy lifting and data management/maintenance tasks.

Comment: Follow Sean's advice. And remove all those "Range().Select" that are useless and slow.

Comment: For VBA Beginner, I strongly recommend reading [This](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm) article

Answer (score 0):

There is no Register type in VBA.

Your issue is probably related to what the loops are doing rather than variable type declarations.

Have you tried turning off Screen Updating to save resources:

```
Application.screenupdating=false ' at the start
' do the work
Application.screenupdating=true ' at the end
```

HTH
Philip